# code throws an exception when i directly run the helper class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

The following code fetches the name of the photo from the database given the user email.

```
package NonServletFiles;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.naming.*;
public class GetPhotosForTheUser {

public ResultSet getData(String email) {
    ResultSet set = null;
    try {
        String sqlQuery = "select nameofthephoto from photocaptions where useremail='" + email + "'";
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/photog"); // LINE 17
        Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        set = statement.executeQuery();
        while(set.next()){
            System.out.println("Name Of The Photo : " + set.getString("NameOfThePhoto"));
        }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    return set;
  }
}
```

If i call this helper class from a `.jsp` file as :

```
    <% 
        GetPhotosForTheUser gpftu = new GetPhotosForTheUser();
        gpftu.getData("suhailgupta03@gmail.com");
    %>
```

it prints the right name on the server console.

But if i use this class alone by adding the `main` method

[image]

in that helper class,it throws an exception which are :

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jdbc/photog' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation ]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at NonServletFiles.GetPhotosForTheUser.getData(GetPhotosForTheUser.java:17)
at NonServletFiles.GetPhotosForTheUser.main(GetPhotosForTheUser.java:32)
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation 
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.getComponentId(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:873)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:742)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:172)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
... 4 more
```

why does it happen ? I am using *glassfish server and netbeans for this development*.

Answer (score 3):

When you run this as web application you Context is initialized with server details

```
Context context = new InitialContext(); // This is initialized when you run as web app
```

When you run as standalone program by calling main method the same is not true

you can get rid of this by initializing your context.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "your provider"); // like for websphere it is com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory and weblogic weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "server path"); //
Context context = new InitialContext(prop);
```

Note: Generally you don't write it like that instead your code will check if it is running in WEBMODE or TEST and in case test it will initialize Context or else it will just use the normal context.

this will initialize your context and you would be able to run it from main method.

Edit: Glassfish configuration taken from [here](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html)

```
  Properties props = new Properties();

  props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", 
                    "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");

  props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", 
                    "com.sun.enterprise.naming");

  props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
                    "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");


  // optional.  Defaults to localhost.  Only needed if web server is running 
  // on a different host than the appserver    
  props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");

  // optional.  Defaults to 3700.  Only needed if target orb port is not 3700.
  props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

  InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run it using the main method, you're not executing it as a web application, and thus you don't have a web application context.